# C11 (and later) does not impose any requirements on raising floating-point exceptions for various operators if Annex F is not supported?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, language-lawyer, c11

Consider that Annex F is not supported and an implementation does not follow IEEE 754.

Then what are the C11 requirements on raising floating-point exceptions for these operators:

```
Equality operators:   == !=
Relational operators: > >= < <=
```

I cannot find such requirements. Does it mean that they are not defined?

Note: at least for "arithmetic operations" we have this (C11, 5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h>):

> A quiet NaN propagates through almost every arithmetic operation without raising a floating-point exception; a signaling NaN generally raises a floating-point exception when occurring as an arithmetic operand.

However, it says "*almost* every arithmetic operation", i.e. w/o mentioning which exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot find such requirements. Does it mean that they are not defined?

I do not find any such requirements either, nor anything from which such requirements could be constructed.  In this regard, it may be relevant to observe that footnote 22 clarifies (somewhat) the quoted section of 5.2.4.2.2/3:

> IEC 60559:1989 specifies quiet and signaling NaNs. For implementations
> that do not support IEC 60559:1989, the terms quiet NaN and signaling
> NaN are intended to apply to encodings with similar behavior.

This "similar" is the context in which "almost every arithmetic operation" should be understood for implementations that do not support Annex F.

No specifics are given as far as I can determine, and I think that's intentional.  C has traditionally supported a wide variety of hardware, and of floating-point behavior in particular.  Generally, C implementations do not isolate programs from the behavior of the FP hardware on which they run.

Comment: For math.h functions C2x (n2596.pdf) requires raising of  floating-point exceptions. Examples are "the "divide-by-zero" floating-point exception is raised" or "the "invalid" floating-point exception is raised". However, if an implementation does not conform to the specifications in the Annex F, then it seems that C itself imposes no requirements on raising of floating-point exceptions for equality operators (`== !=`) and for relational operators (`> >= < <=`).